# Automatically resize div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

http://jsfiddle.net/maes222/AtPf2/

Can someone help me to fit my content in the div tag. If i add some more `<li>` then the div tag should be resized automatically.
Now i am confused with many styles. Where i might have gone wrong?
Thanks

**CSS**

```
#qhse
        {

        background-color: #92DF7B; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        opacity: 0.1;

        }

a.icon{
    width:52px;
    height:52px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? If you don't set the `height` of the `div`, it will automatically resize.

Comment: But i tried without setting height as well as setting height to auto.

Comment: Do you want to make an accordion? So that if you click on the `div`, it collapses/expands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update these two css classes as:

```
#qhse {
   background-color: #92DF7B;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.item ul {
   list-style:none;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
.item ul {display:none;}
```

and add

```
.item ul {border: solid 1px;}
```

and see?

Comment: I want a box around the items in div tag if i remove that i am not getting the box.

Answer (score 0):

Your  is not visible and it has position:absolute so it wont grow your surrounding div;

```
.item ul{
  list-style:none;
  position: relative;
}
```

Maybe you can show us how it should look like and how it should behave.